# Laravel Collection helper put() issue

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I need to understand once and for all this. Sorry for a silly question.

I have the following Static Method that essentially gets a table of `id`s and `php_format`s for dates.

As I get the data, I want to add a column to each row of the collection, so that it contains `today` formatted by `Carbon`. I [understood the `put()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-put) does this.

My method:

```
public static function getWithSampleDates($type = null)
{
    if (! $type) {
        $dates = self::all();
    } else {
        $dates = self::where('type', '=', $type)->get();
    }

    foreach($dates as $date) {
        $date->put('label', Carbon::now()->format($date->php_format));
    }

    return $dates;
}
```

But this fails with:

```
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::put()
```

I do not understand. I thought `$dates` is a `collection`?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to use `setAttribute()` although I am still confused about the use of `put()`.

```
public static function getWithSampleDates($type = null)
{
    if (! $type) {
        $dates = self::get();
    } else {
        $dates = self::where('type', '=', $type)->get();
    }

    foreach($dates as $date) {
        $date->setAttribute('label', Carbon::now()->format($date->php_format));
    }

    return $dates;
}
```